# Why does glut32.lib work with codeblocks/gcc, I thought only *.a libraries worked with gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries

So that is my question, I though *.lib were Microsoft specific yet glut32.lib linked fine with gcc?

Comment: What happens at runtime?

Comment: It asks for glut32.dll also, but it all compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows port of GNU binutils (which GCC uses to link your application) uses the same format PECOFF format objects, libraries and executables as Microsoft's development tools. Whether the library is called `libfoo.a` or `foo.lib`, so long as it's in the PECOFF library format the linker will be able to use it.

This doesn't necessarily mean that the code in the library is compatible with the code you're linking it to. Since `glut32.lib` is apparently just an import library it shouldn't cause any incompatibilities itself. The DLL `glut32.dll` might be a problem, but other people have used precompiled versions of GLUT with MinGW before: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Use_Mark_J_Kilgards_OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit_GLUT_with_MinGW